# Ember data: what is difference between find and findById?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

It is unclear to me what the difference is between the following 2 find methods:

```
model: function (params) {
    return App.Publication.findById(params.publication_id);  
  },

model: function (params) {
    return App.Publication.find(params.publication_id);
  },
```

I experienced problems when using the findbyId method in a transition.retry; in that case, the model did not load causing errors when transitioning ...  See also [Ember: route ID is lost after a transition.retry() - Am I doing something wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297560/ember-route-id-is-lost-after-a-transition-retry-am-i-doing-something-wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are talking about the `DS.Store`, because `DS.Model` doesn't have a `findById` method.

The diference between, `find` and `findById` in store is that findById like the name says: will find the data by id. And find have a polymorphic way to find records based in your parameters:

- Calling store.find(App.Publication, 1 /* number of string */), will peform a store.findById
- With store.find(App.Publication), will perform a store.findAll
- and store.find(App.Publication, { name: 'Tom' }), call store.findQuery

DS.Model.find have a alias to store.find, so to make a findById, just call App.Publication.find(1 /* number of string */)

Comment: I was indeed confused here. Should not use findById on a model. Thx.