# Ember data difference between find() and getById()

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I know that there is a question named : [Ember data: what is difference between find and findById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299352/ember-data-what-is-difference-between-find-and-findbyid). However, correct if I'm wrong, but I think that it relates to an older version of Ember data since I can't find this method in the [embet-data doc](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_getById).

I was trying to insert a new category in my catalog. This wouldn't work:

```
newRecord: function() {
    catalog = this.store.find('catalog', 1);
    record = this.store.createRecord( 'category', {category_name_fr_sh: 'Nouvelle categorie'});
    catalog.get('catalog_categories_ids').pushObject(record);
    this.set('content', record);
},
```

But this work :

```
newRecord: function() {
    catalog = this.store.getById('catalog', 1);
    record = this.store.createRecord( 'category', {category_name_fr_sh: 'Nouvelle categorie'});
    catalog.get('catalog_categories_ids').pushObject(record);
    this.set('content', record);
},
```

The doc says

> Get a record by a given type and ID without triggering a fetch.
>   This method will synchronously return the record if it's available. Otherwise, it will return null.

I really don't understand why "trggering the fetch" wouldn't work. I tought that the find() first look if it's in the store cache and only fetch if it doesn't find it. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question with care :-( I deleted my anwser

Comment: How are your model defined? Can you provide a JsFiddle or similar?

Comment: @Edu Sure, I don't have the time right away, but I'll post one when I'm back from work. Thanks for helping

Comment: when you say "wouldn't work" what do you mean? Do you mean you had another instance of catalog-id-1 somewhere that doesn't get the new category? If so you need to use that instance. `getById` is returning a reference to a fetched record if it exists; `find` is giving you a __new__ "mirror" of that object, not connected to existing ones.

Comment: @MichaelJohnston I had an error thrown and my catalog when I tried to access properties. It was "undefined".

Comment: actually I think ember-data is one "session" conceptually, and to have separate instances of an object you have to explicitly start a transaction, so two references to an object by `find(id)` are connected. I use epf, which can have multiple sessions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.store.find('catalog', 1);` doesn't return the record, it return a `DS.PromiseObject`. Because, if your record is not present in the record cache, a request to the server is needed. If the record is already loaded, you still have the promise object, to keep the same method behavior, but no request is sent to the server.

`this.store.getById('catalog', 1);` return the object from the record cache if present. Probably this work because you already loaded the catalogs using `this.store.find('catalog');` or `this.store.find('catalog', 1);`

You can get the catalog record from `DS.PromiseObject` using `then` method:

```
newRecord: function() {
    var self = this;
    var catalogPromise = this.store.find('catalog', 1);
    catalogPromise.then(function(catalog) {
        var record = this.store.createRecord( 'category', {category_name_fr_sh: 'Nouvelle categorie'});
        catalog.get('catalog_categories_ids').pushObject(record);
        self.set('content', record);
    })
},
```

Comment: by the way, this is something you have to do when setting controller models programmatically outside of a route's model hook as well.